# Creating a Jquery update function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I create an update function in javascript/jquery?

An update function is a function that is run at each step in the game, say 60 times a second for example.  It is used a lot in game development.

How can I make something like this in jquery?

Comment: @Lix How many games have you played where nothing happens more than once a minute?

Comment: @ant - no one is saying that the entire game engine depends on this one interval.  But if you want an example [here it is](http://www.rrrrthats5rs.com/games/dont-shoot-the-puppy/).  There are some *useless* games out there :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SetInterval will be useful to you in this instance.

You can use it like this -

```
var timer = setInterval(callback,delay);
```

This code will execute a function named `callback` every `delay` miliseconds.

To stop the timer, you can use the `clearInterval()` method.

```
clearInterval(timer);
```

As I stated, the intervals are defined in **milliseconds** so in order for your callback to execute 60 times a second you would need to pass 16 or 17 milliseconds as the `delay` parameter.

Comment: 60 times a second was the example given.  Any interval could be used.

Comment: @dav - I think someone else was not pleased with the constructive criticism I gave on their answer... It has since been deleted by the user... Feel free to vote here and "fix" that ugly `-1` if you feel that my post helped you :)

Answer (score 3):

Probably you need to use [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Window.setInterval) function.

But I would recommend to use [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.requestAnimationFrame) instead as it was designed for  developing browser games and can perform 60 calls per second as you need.

Answer (score 2):

why jQuery? just call a function with a frequency of `1000/60` msecs, e.g.

```
setInterval(function() {
  ...
}, 1000/60)
```

Answer (score 1):

That will partially depend on your rendering method.
If you will be rendering your "game" in (for instance) a `<canvas>` element, you might want to use [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.requestAnimationFrame) (a javascript native function)

For more information see [This helpfull article](http://athousandnodes.com/article/using-requestanimationframe-web-browser-animations-instead-settimeout)